# Get the latest data in SQL

Tags: sql

I am hoping to get some help in relation to the SQL query to pull the latest data till yesterday.

I have a main table called clickstream, this table has all the website activity and has a date column called businesseffectivedate, which provides the breakdown of each day's performance (visits, clicks, sales), etc.

I have create a query based on my requirement and I call this, TableA. My goal is to update the TableA every day based on the businesseffectivedate.

The data I want is, from August 1st, and for the end date I would like to get the latest data (i.e. yesterday Sep 23) I tried using the “current_date()” inside Where clause to get the latest data every day.
I was hoping that, I should get the latest data till yesterday based on the current_date() but I am still seeing the latest date is 22nd Sep (even when I refreshed the data today, ideally the date should be 23rd Sept instead.

1st Query (Tried and not working):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.tableA;
CREATE TABLE db.tableA as
Select clicks, impressions, businesseffectivedate, sales from clickstream
where businesseffectivedate > '2022-07-31' and businesseffectivedate < current_date()
```

2nd Query (Tried and not working):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.tableA;
CREATE TABLE db.tableA as
Select clicks, impressions, businesseffectivedate, sales from clickstream
where businesseffectivedate > '2022-07-31' and businesseffectivedate <= date_add(current_date(),-1)
```

3rd Query (Not tried yet):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.tableA;
CREATE TABLE db.tableA as
Select clicks, impressions, businesseffectivedate, sales from clickstream
where businesseffectivedate > '2022-07-31' and businesseffectivedate < (select max(businesseffectivedate) from clickstream)
```

for clickstream data I ran this command,
select max(businesseffectivedate) from clickstream  // This gives me the answer of 2022-09-23 (correct)

I ran the same command for my tableA since the data in this table is coming from clickstream.

```
select max(businesseffectivedate) from tableA   //  I am seeing 2022-09-22 (in-correct)
```

Please advise how I can make this query automate (i.e. get the latest data everyday). FYI, I am SQL newbie and don’t have much experience with code, and not familiar with ROW/partition by etc.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like an ETL job, You can make from_date and to_date a function of sysdate and populate data. Also, if you just need incremental data you can implement it in that way instead of dropping table every time. And job can be scheduled at a particular periodic time based on the requirement. Once the requirement is detailed enough you can start the implementation. Good Luck!

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: i would use Airflow :)

Comment: It's still unclear which DBMS is in use.

Answer (score 0):

I think that will extract data for a day (MySQL)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.tableA;
CREATE TABLE db.tableA as
Select clicks, impressions, businesseffectivedate, sales from clickstream
where DATE(businesseffectivedate) = '2022-07-31'
```